# Memory leak sqlite3MemMalloc in iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, memory-leaks

I am getting sqlite3Memmalloc leak in my instruments tool in iphone. My app is consuming memory of more than 200 MB. In the memory management instrument it shows Responsible Library as libsqlite3.dylib & Responsible caller as sqlite3MemMalloc. In my app I am trying to insert 2000 rows.I think due to the memory usage the app gets crashed. I have checked in all aspects but not able to find the error leak in my sqlite code. Please provide me a solution. Below is my sqlite code.

```
- (Boolean) insertQuotes:(QuotesInfo*)quote
  {

NSString *dbPath = [dBManager GetConnectToDatabase];
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt=nil;
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    if(selectstmt == nil)
    {

        NSString* Query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Quotes (QuoteID,QuoteDate,QuoteDesc,QuoteAuthor,QuoteCategory,QuoteCategoryID,QuoteAuthorID,QuoteFavourite,QuoteCategoryFilterStatus,QuoteAuthorFilterStatus,AuthorFirstName,AuthorLastName) values (%d, '%@', %@, '%@', '%@', %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, '%@', '%@')",quote.quoteId,quote.quoteDate,quote.quoteDesc,quote.quoteAuthor,quote.quoteCategory,quote.quoteCategoryID,quote.quoteAuthorID,quote.quoteFav,quote.quoteCategoryFilterStatus,quote.quoteAuthorFilterStatus,quote.authorFirstName,quote.authorLastName];

        NSLog(@"Query %@",Query);
        const char *sql = [Query UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
    @try {

    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {

        return  NO;

        NSLog(@"INSERT EXCEPTION %@",e);
        //Handle the Exception here..
    }

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(selectstmt)){
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    else{
        sqlite3_reset(selectstmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return YES;
      }
    }
  return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of horrible bugs in that code, but the ones related to memory leaks are:

- you do not always call `sqlite3_finalize` after `sqlite3_prepare_v2` has succeeded; and
- you do not always call `sqlite3_close` after `sqlite3_open` has succeeded.

You must not hide those calls in some `if`/`else` branch.
Restructure your code so that these calls are always made.